# jQuery / javascript 'not well-formed' error for a simple XML file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, xml

I have the next PHP file generating XML data:

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset: utf-8');
echo "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
    <xml>
        <names>
            <nameID>22</nameID>
            <name>x</name>
        </names>
        <names>
            <nameID>288</nameID>
            <name>y</name>
        </names>
    </xml>";
```

[I have inserted tabs here for readability, original file echos everything on one line]

This is sent to the following jQuery `ajax()` function successfully:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml){
        $(xml).find('names').each(function(){
          var name_string = $(this).find('name').text();
          var name_id = $(this).find('nameID').text();

          // Render name on page
          var name_html = "<div class='name' data-id='" + name_id + "'>" + name_string + "</div>";
          $("main-names-display").append(name_html); 
        });
      },

      error: function() {
        alert("An error occurred while processing XML file.");
      }
    });
```

This results in a `not well-formed` error with no further details. **The error repeats every `$(xml).find('names').each(...`**

I have tried looking into similar questions but found no reason for such a simple xml structure to fail. What exactly isn't 'well-formed'?

Comment: What if you change the escaped double quotes to be normal double quotes and surround the xml with single quotes? I don't have any php experience so I may just be stabbing in the dark.

Comment: When I replicate that code [on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nqmot2o5/1/), I can't reproduce the problem.